# What are the new shortcuts for Windows 8?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-8

I loved the keyboard shortcuts in Windows 7 (i.e. <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> moves a window to the left side of the screen), but I'm not sure on what some of the new ones might be for Windows 8.  What are all of the NEW keyboard shortcuts that I can use while working in Windows 8?

Comment: Wow, I've never heard about Win + ←

Answer (score 52, accepted):

How-To Geek has compiled [a list of the new shortcut keys](http://www.howtogeek.com/107182/get-to-know-the-new-shortcut-keys-in-windows-8/) in Windows 8:

- <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> – brings up the Modern UI start screen. You can start typing to search for an app, just like the Win7 start menu.
- <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> – brings up the old Windows desktop.
- <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> – brings up the Charms menu, where you can search, share, and change settings.
- <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> – opens the Settings panel, where you can change settings for the current app, change volume, wireless networks, shut down, or adjust the brightness.
- <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> – opens the App Bar for the current Metro application.
- <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> – opens the Modern UI Share panel.
- <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> – brings up the Modern UI App Search screen.
- <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> – brings up the Modern UI Settings search screen.
- <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> – brings up the Modern UI File search screen.
- <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> – opens the Devices panel (for connecting to a projector or some other device)
- <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> (comma) – Aero Peek at the desktop.
- <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> (period) – Snaps the current Metro application to one side of the screen. (Right side)
- <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> (period)  – Snaps the current Metro application to the other side of the screen. (Left side)
- <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> – switches focus between snapped Metro applications.
- <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>Page Up</kbd> / <kbd>Page Down</kbd> – moves the current app to the other monitor.
- <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> – opens the Modern UI application switcher menu, switches between applications.
- <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> – opens the Advanced User menu.

A [more comprehensive list](http://www.pcworld.com/article/251022/windows_8_consumer_preview_keyboard_shortcuts.html) - including the shortcuts unchanged from Windows 7 - can be found at PCWorld.

Answer (score 22):

May be there are more and you know it but at this time I got this one in Windows explorer. Just select the file by clicking on it and then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> now the under the "View" menu you will see the options and with these options you will see their shortcuts respectively. If you want to hide this file/folder then after pressing the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> you have to press the <kbd>HS</kbd> and it will be hidden. For showing hidden item just press the <kbd>H</kbd> key.

[image]

The same for the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> where you can share, burn to disc, even zip the file with the shortcuts.

[image]

after pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> will let you

> <kbd>CO</kbd>= copy  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
>
> <kbd>C</kbd>= cut  similar to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
>
> <kbd>CP</kbd>= copy path
>
> <kbd>V</kbd>= paste  similar to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
>
> <kbd>PS</kbd>= paste shortcut
>
> <kbd>SA</kbd>= select all while <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> still
> works

and more are listed with options.

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>=<kbd>Win</kbd> key

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>: Switch between Modern Desktop Start screen and the last accessed application

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>: Access the charms bar

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>: Access the Modern Desktop Taskbar

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>: Access the Settings charm

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>: Access the Share charm

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>: Access the Devices charm

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>: Access the Apps Search screen

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>: Access the Files Search screen

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>: Access the Settings Search screen

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>: Access the Second Screen bar

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>: Brings up the App Bar when you have a Modern Desktop App running

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>: Access the Windows Tools Menu

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>: Lock screen orientation

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> : Move the screen split to the right

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> : Move the screen split to the left

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>: View all active Toasts/Notifications

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + V: View all active Toasts/Notifications in reverse order

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>PrtScn</kbd>: Takes a screenshot of the screen and automatically saves it in the Pictures folder as Screenshot

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>: Launch Narrator

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>: Open Computer

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>: Open the Run dialog box

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>: Open Ease of Access Center

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>: Open Find Computers dialog box

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>Pause/Break</kbd>: Open the System page

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>1..10</kbd>: Launch a program pinned on the Taskbar in the position indicated by the number

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>1..10</kbd>: Launch a new instance of a program pinned on the Taskbar in the position indicated by the number

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1..10</kbd>: Access the last active instance of a program pinned on the Taskbar in the position indicated by the number

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1..10</kbd>: Access the Jump List of a program pinned on the Taskbar in the position indicated by the number

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>: Select the first item in the Notification Area and then use the arrow keys to cycle through the items Press Enter to open the selected item

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>: Access the program that is displaying a message in the Notification Area

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>: Cycle through the items on the Taskbar

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>: Minimize all windows

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>: Restore all minimized windows

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>: Show/Hide Desktop (minimize/restore all windows)

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>: Lock computer

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>Up Arrow</kbd>: Maximize current window

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>+ <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>: Minimize/restore current window

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd>: Minimize all but the current window

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>: Tile window on the left side of the screen

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>: Tile window on the right side of the screen

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Up Arrow</kbd>: Extend current window from the top to the bottom of the screen

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left/Right Arrow</kbd>: Move the current window from one monitor to the next

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>+ <kbd>F1</kbd>: Launch Windows Help and Support

<kbd>PageUp</kbd>: Scroll forward on the Modern Desktop Start screen

<kbd>PageDown</kbd>: Scroll backward on the Modern Desktop Start screen

<kbd>Esc</kbd>: Close  a charm

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>: Switch between Modern Desktop Start screen and the last accessed application

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Mouse scroll wheel: Activate the Semantic Zoom on the Modern Desktop screen

<kbd>Alt</kbd>: Display a hidden Menu Bar

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>: Select the Address Bar

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>: Display the Preview Pane in Windows Explorer

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>: Cycle forward through open windows

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>: Cycle backward through open windows

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>: Close the current window Open the Shut Down Windows dialog box from the Desktop

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>: Access the Shortcut menu for current window

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>: Cycle between open programs in the order that they were opened

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>: Open the Properties dialog box of the selected item

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>PrtScn</kbd>: Take a screen shot of the active Window and place it in the clipboard

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Up Arrow</kbd>: Move up one folder level in Windows Explorer (Like the <kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> in XP)

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>: Display the previous folder

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>: Display the next folder

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd>: CD/DVD Load CD/DVD without triggering Autoplay or Autorun

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>: Permanently delete the item (rather than sending it to the Recycle Bin)

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>: Cycle backward through elements in a window or dialog box

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>: Access the context menu for the selected item

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>: Cycle backward through elements in a window or dialog box

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd>: Select a consecutive group of items

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> on a Taskbar button: Launch a new instance of a program

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Right-click</kbd> on a Taskbar button: Access the context menu for the selected item

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>: Select all items

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>: Copy the selected item

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>: Cut the selected item

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>: Paste the selected item

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>: Delete selected item

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>: Undo an action

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd>: Redo an action

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>: Open a new window in Windows Explorer

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>: Close current window in Windows Explorer

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>: Select the Search box in the upper right corner of a window

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>: Create new folder

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>: Open the Windows Task Manager

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>: Use arrow keys to cycle through open windows

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>: Access the Windows Security screen

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd>: Select multiple individual items

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> and drag an item: Copies that item in the same folder

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> and drag an item: Creates a shortcut for that item in the same folder

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>:  Move forward through tabs

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>: Move backward through tabs

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> on a Taskbar button: Launch a new instance of a program as an Administrator

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> on a grouped Taskbar button: Cycle through the instances of a program in the group

<kbd>F1</kbd>: Display Help

<kbd>F2</kbd>: Rename a file

<kbd>F3</kbd>: Open Search

<kbd>F4</kbd>: Display the Address Bar list

<kbd>F5</kbd>: Refresh display

<kbd>F6</kbd>: Cycle forward through elements in a window or dialog box

<kbd>F7</kbd>: Display command history in a Command Prompt

<kbd>F10</kbd>: Display hidden Menu Bar

<kbd>F11</kbd>: Toggle full screen display

<kbd>Tab</kbd>: Cycle forward through elements in a window or dialog box

<kbd>PrtScn</kbd>: Take a screen shot of the entire screen and place it in the clipboard

<kbd>Home</kbd>: Move to the top of the active window

<kbd>End</kbd>: Move to the bottom of the active window

<kbd>Delete</kbd>: Delete the selected item

<kbd>Backspace</kbd>: Display the previous folder in Windows Explorer  Move up one folder level in Open or Save dialog box

<kbd>Esc</kbd>: Close a dialog box

<kbd>Num Lock</kbd> Enabled + <kbd>+</kbd>: Display the contents of the selected folder

<kbd>Num Lock</kbd> Enabled + <kbd>-</kbd>: Collapse the selected folder

<kbd>Num Lock</kbd> Enabled + <kbd>*</kbd>: Expand all subfolders under the selected folder

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> 5 times Turn StickyKeys on or off
Hold down right <kbd>Shift</kbd> for 8 seconds Turn FilterKeys on or off
Hold down <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> for 5 seconds Turn ToggleKeys on or off

From [MSDN Blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/hyperyash/list-of-windows-8-shortcuts)

[Microsoft KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-dcc61a57-8ff0-cffe-9796-cb9706c75eec) for more shortcuts while they have listed normal.

Comment: Definitely bounty worthy!

Comment: @avirk Tremendous !!

Answer (score 14):

If you are a developer, this is one of the commands you’ll love the most:

<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> `->` <kbd>A</kbd>

Starts a command prompt with administrator privileges.

Answer (score 0):

With Windows 8 and Windows RT, you can use the keyboard shortcuts you're already using as well as:

- [New keyboard shortcuts for Windows 8 and Windows RT](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/new-keyboard-shortcuts).

For a bigger list of keyboard shortcuts relating to Windows 8 and Windows RT see [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/keyboard-shortcuts).