# Is there a shortcut for Aero Peek in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the new shortcuts for Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/466789/what-are-the-new-shortcuts-for-windows-8)

Aero Peek is disabled by default in Windows 8, but you can get it back via Taskbar Properties:

[image: Aero Peek checkbox in Windows 8]

However, the old shortcut <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd> no longer works - is there a replacement, or a way to get the old keyboard shortcut working?

Comment: Can someone integrate my answer into the other answer, as my html skills suck or I would do it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>

New hotkeys for Windows 8:

```
Key combination:     Windows 8 functionality:
Windows+Space       Switch input language and keyboard layout.
Windows+O           Lock device orientation.
Windows+,           Temporarily peek at the desktop.
Windows+V           Cycle through toasts.
Windows+Shift-V     Cycle through toasts in reverse order.
Windows+Enter       Launch Narrator.
Windows+PgUp        Move the Start Screen or a Metro-style application to the monitor on the left.
Windows+PgDown      Move the Start Screen or a Metro-style application to the monitor on the right.
Windows+Shift-.     Move the gutter to the left (snap an application).
Windows+.           Move the gutter to the right (snap an application).
Windows+C           Open the Charms bar.
Windows+I           Open the Settings charm.
Windows+K           Open the Connect charm.
Windows+H           Open the Share charm.
Windows+Q           Open the Search pane.
Windows+W           Open the Settings Search app.
Windows+F           Open the File Search app.
Windows+Tab         Cycle through apps.
Windows+Shift-Tab   Cycle through apps in reverse order.
Windows+Ctrl-Tab    Cycle through apps and snap them as they cycle.
Windows+Z           Open the App Bar.
Windows+/           Initiate input method editor (IME) reconversion.
Windows+J           Swap foreground between the snapped and filled apps.
Windows+Printscreen It takes and saves the screenshot. It places the saved screenshot into your pictures folder as a PNG.
```

Comment: This works for Windows 10, too