# Keyboard shortcut to search Settings in Windows 8?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the new shortcuts for Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/466789/what-are-the-new-shortcuts-for-windows-8)

If you press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> button and start typing, it will search all your apps. If you press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, it will search your Files. Is there a similar keyboard shortcut that you can use to search in Settings, without having to use the mouse?

Comment: I just realized. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there actually is

- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>: Search apps
- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>: Search settings
- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>: Search files