# Open charms via keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-8, charms-bar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the new shortcuts for Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/466789/what-are-the-new-shortcuts-for-windows-8)

Is there a keyboard shortcut to open the charms in Windows 8?

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is the shortcut for opening the Charms bar.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of shortcuts for the charms bar:

- <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>: Open charms
- <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>: Search charm
- <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>: Share charm
- <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>: Devices charm
- <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>: Settings charm