# Where to find the Windows 8 Product ID (PID)

Tags: windows-8

I need to file a support request to Microsoft, and will need my Product ID (PID) for this.

Annoyingly, [the official knowledge base](http://support.microsoft.com/gp/PIDWin) does not contain an answer to Windows 8 users on where to find this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find the PID, you need to go to your `System` page, which can be done by one of three ways:

1. Go to `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System` by copy-pasting this into the “address bar” of an Explorer window.
2. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> and click on `Control Panel`. After this, go to `System`.
3. Use the desktop Charm to go to `Control Panel`. Go to `System` afterwards.

Or do as @avirk and press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Break/Pause</kbd>.

In here, you will find the information you need at the bottom:

[image: Product ID]

Comment: Well you should activate Windows :-)

Comment: I actually can’t, smartypants, but that’s a different SU question for another time. ;p

Comment: It is not genuine eh? :P

Comment: It is. I’ll just wait and see what Microsoft have to say, once they respond at some point tomorrow.

Comment: oh i see... good luck :)

Answer (score 3):

Just press the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>PauseBreak</kbd> and you will able to see the sytem information windows and at the bottom you will see the Product ID of Windows.

[image]

Comment: @BojanKogoj if you interested in shortcuts see http://superuser.com/questions/466789/what-are-the-new-shortcuts-for-windows-8

Answer (score 0):

Simply use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Pause/Break</kbd> to open the System window. Then, scroll down to Windows activation and you will see the Product ID listed there.