# Getting Windows 8 Product ID through command-line

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-8, product-id

I know it is possible to find the Windows 8 Product ID [in the "System" page located in the Control Panel](https://superuser.com/a/494712/138020).

But is it possible to get the Windows 8 Product ID using the command prompt?

Comment: You are aware the Product Id is NOT the key you use to install with, right? :)

Comment: @techie007 Yes, of course.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are a few ways suitable for use in batch files:

```
wmic os get "SerialNumber" | find /v "SerialNumber"

for /f "tokens=3" %p in ('SystemInfo ^| find "Product ID"') do @echo %p

for /f "tokens=3" %p in ('reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v ProductID') do @echo %p
```

Comment: `wmic os get "SerialNumber"` works great.

Comment: Yup, the extra find bit is just so it returns the PID only and no other text, so you can easily assign it to a variable for example.

Comment: Actually it still return "SerialNumber" text.

Comment: Are you sure? It doesn't for me, if I use the entire command specified with the find bit included. I tested all 3 before posting.

Comment: Yes, type it and you will see that the text "SerialNumber" comes before the ID itself. Test it by using a pipe, for example wmic os get "SerialNumber" > txt.txt, then open txt.txt on notepad.

Comment: Hmm, probably you are reffering to the entire script, from the answer, I'm talking about wmic os get "SerialNumber" from @amiregelz comment, sorry.

Comment: Precisely. The `find /v` bit removes all other lines except the one displaying the SerialNumber.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible by using WMI (Windows Management Interface)
or by querying a value from Windows Registry.

**With WMI:**

1. From the command line, type the `wmic` (and <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
2. Inside WMI, Type `OS`
3. Look over "SerialNumber" value. It contains your Windows 8 ProductID.

P.S.: Alternatively, you could also type `wmic OS` from cmd
and search for "SerialNumber".

[Reference.](http://alexmg.com/post/2010/09/21/Getting-the-Windows-Product-ID-using-WMI.aspx)

**With Windows Registry:**

1. Just type the folowing command from cmd:

   ```
   reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v ProductID
   ```

   or even:

   ```
   reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Registration" /v ProductID
   ```

   (Internet Explorer has the same ID as Windows 8.)

Comment: This returns a very long line of text (or a very messy text if I type `wmic OS`). Is it possible to get only the Product ID?

Comment: Edited, by using the second method yes...(It looks weird but Internet Explorer have the same ID as Windows)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Windows' [`SystemInfo` command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491007.aspx).

It will return a list of info about the system, including that Product ID (about the 9th line down give or take.)

From MS:

> Displays detailed configuration information about a computer and its
>   operating system, including operating system configuration, security
>   information, ***product ID***, and hardware properties, such as RAM, disk
>   space, and network cards.

If you want to extract just that line you can use
`systeminfo | find /i "product id"`.

Comment: Is it possible to get the Product ID exclusively?

Comment: @amiregelz Yeah there is, at least just that line; see my updated answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

use following command:

```
wmic path softwarelicensingservice get OA3xOriginalProductKey
```

Tested on my genuine @in 8.1 64 bit.
Reference - http://www.thewindowsclub.com/find-windows-product-key