# Transfer Windows 8 licence from VMWare to new installation

Tags: windows-8, license, licensing

I installed an internet-purchased Windows 8 license ($40) in VMWare Player when it first came out because I wasn't sure I wanted to move from Windows 7. Now, I want to install Windows 8 on the main partition (C: drive). How do I transfer the licence from the VMWare installation to the actual computer? I want to delete the VMWare installation, but I am wary of doing so, until I have solved the issue that Microsoft indicates exists - that I have used the licence elsewhere.

Comment: You refer to this question which is similar.. http://superuser.com/questions/499088/transferring-a-windows-8-license-and-proper-un-and-reinstallation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This shouldn't be a problem- retail keys can be transferred.

Install Windows 8 on your PC, then activate it using that license key.

If it doesn't work because it's already been used on your VM, call Microsoft and attempt a telephone activation. If that doesn't work, speak with a Microsoft rep, and explain your situation to them, and they should give you another key to use.

Finally, once you have successfully activated your PC, you can delete the virtual machine.

Comment: Never used SuperUser before. You have a convert. Thanks for the very quick response. Will try it when day breaks - in Accra.

Comment: @Olad If it does work, the standard way to show thanks is to click the arrow next to his post, which accepts the answer (telling everyone else that it solved your problem).

Comment: I had to call the UK line... Activation center closest to here spoke French! Many thanks.