# Windows 8 short cut keys

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the new shortcuts for Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/466789/what-are-the-new-shortcuts-for-windows-8)

Is there any definitive list of new shortcut keys for Windows 8?  I've read or discovered thinks like <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> and <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScn</kbd>, but I'm sure there are plenty more out there that were added/changed/etc with this new UI, and am curious if there's a good, maybe even definitive list of these keys?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some good ones:

> [How To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/107182/get-to-know-the-new-shortcut-keys-in-windows-8/)
>       Windows key – brings up the Metro start screen. You can start typing to search for an app, just like the Win7 start menu.
>       Win + D – brings up the old Windows desktop.
>       Win + C – brings up the Charms menu, where you can search, share, and change settings.
>       Win + I – opens the Settings panel, where you can change settings for the current app, change volume, wireless networks, shut down, or adjust the brightness.
>       Win + Z – opens the App Bar for the current Metro application.
>       Win + H – opens the Metro Share panel.
>       Win + Q – brings up the Metro App Search screen.
>       Win + W – brings up the Metro Settings search screen.
>       Win + F – brings up the Metro File search screen.
>       Win + K – opens the Devices panel (for connecting to a projector or some other device)
>       Win + ,  (comma) – Aero Peek at the desktop.
>       Win + .  (period) – Snaps the current Metro application to one side of the screen. (Right side)
>       Win + Shift + . (period)  – Snaps the current Metro application to the other side of the screen. (Left side)
>       Win + J – switches focus between snapped Metro applications.
>       Win + Page Up / Down – moves the current app to the other monitor.
>       Win + Tab – opens the Metro application switcher menu, switches between applications.

Here is a [more exhaustive list](http://www.pcworld.com/article/251022/windows_8_consumer_preview_keyboard_shortcuts.html#tk.rss_news) (but I am not sure all carried from the Consumer Preview).