# Select "move window" from Win8 desktop taskbar

Tags: windows-8, taskbar, extended-desktop

I have my TV connected as "extended desktop". I start the VLC video player in a resizeable window on my primary monitor, drag it to the extended desktop, and hit "F" for full-screen. Then I settle dowm to watch my movie.

I have a full-size keyboard and my favourite mouse on the desk with my PC, plus a USB/wireless mini keyboard+mousepad gizmo that I only use to watch movies (I normally only use the *space = pause* key on the gizmo).

When the movie finishes, VLC automatically reverts to a resizeable window, and I usually put the TV into "standby" mode then.

On my old XP system, I can right-click the VLC icon in the Taskbar and select "Move" (if the VLC window is currently maximised, I hit "F" to make it resizeable first, otherwise the "Move" option is greyed out).

On my new Win8 system, right-clicking on the icon for a running program in the Taskbar no longer offers the "Move" option.

There may be other ways of doing things, but I'm used to what I've been doing for years. Is there any way to make the Win8 taskbar icons behave the same as they did in XP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably not going to be able to make it act exactly like it did in XP, at least not without hacking/replacing Explorer.exe.

Having said that, in Windows 7/8 you can hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when you right-click the icon on the taskbar and you should get the context menu you're looking for (the one with Move, Restore, Size, Close, etc.)

Comment: That's close enough for me, thanks! Armed with the knowledge that *shift* might be relevant, I've now found [this excellent summary](http://superuser.com/questions/466789/) of shortcuts right here on superuser. I suppose questions like this are pretty basic, so it's no surprise no-one else has voted here - but can I reasonably assume they're not actually *unwelcome?*

Comment: If the question is not acceptable it will get votes to close, and/or a lot of downvotes. :)  Over time this question may generate more points as others search for a similar question/answer.  Your link to the shortcuts question from here will probably also help them.