# Close window from the taskbar?

Tags: windows-8, taskbar

In Windows 7, I was able to right-click on a window's button in the taskbar and get a menu containing an item for closing (or minimizing or maximizing) that window. Is there something I can adjust in Windows 8 to get this same functionality?

Comment: Try ALT+F4. I do not have Win8 so I cannot test it. Works in other releases though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://superuser.com/a/615192/46507

> Having said that, in Windows 7/8 you can hold the Shift key when you right-click the icon on the taskbar and you should get the context menu you're looking for (the one with Move, Restore, Size, Close, etc.)

Comment: You can often do SHIFT + R. Click, C to close a program from the taskbar based on this. Sometimes copy comes up, and you will have to select the proper menu item. Thank you for the shortcut.